# How to do an action when a checkbox is checked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I want to do an action when a user checks a checkbox, but I can't get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

So basically, a user goes to my page, ticks the box, then the alert pops up.

```
if($("#home").is(":checked"))
{
      alert('');
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an Event. JQuery provides simple event binding methods like so

```
$("#home").click(function() {
    // this function will get executed every time the #home element is clicked (or tab-spacebar changed)
    if($(this).is(":checked")) // "this" refers to the element that fired the event
    {
        alert('home is checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: So many years later and your answer still helped me!! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Actually the `change()` function is much better for this solution because it works for javascript generated actions, such as selecting every checkbox via a script.

```
$('#home').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      ... 
   } else {
      ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use the .click event described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn

so

```
$("#home").click( function () {
    if($("#home").is(":checked"))
    {
      alert('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#home").click(function() {
    var checked=this.checked;
    if(checked==true)
        {
         // Stuff here
        }
    else
        {
        //stuff here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "#home" ).change(function() {
    if(this.checked){
        alert("The Check-box is Checked"); // Your Code...
    }else{
        alert("The Check-box is Un-Checked"); // Your Code...
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

for some cases, when you have a dynamic content you can use this code:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','#home',function (e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      alert('Home is checked')
    }else{
      alert('Home is unchecked')
    }
  });
});
```